# Permission problem on SharePoint team sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, team-sites

[image]

A user can add permissions in this site collection.

[image]

However a user can't add permissions in a different site collection. I would like to know why it is not working. The user has full control on both site collection.

Comment: What error user gets when adding permissions and how user is trying to give permission?

Comment: @SharePointer There no error message the user don't see New tab option when trying add another user into a group

Comment: You will need to add more details as both screenshots doesn't give much details.  Is it an AD group? or SharePoint group.  Is this user trying to add permission through site permissions or specific document library/list? have you refreshed the screen and tried different browsers?

Comment: @SharePointer it is SharePoint groups yes through site permissions

Answer (score 2):

Check Group Settings, who is the Group Owner, as by default only Group Owner can add users to that SharePoint group. Group Owner can be a person or another SP group.

[image]

Comment: I fix it :) :) ;) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the group owner! Site Permissions=>Group=>Settings =>Group Owner.

Only Group owners and site collection administrator can add users to Groups

Comment: i fix it :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

First, go to site settings -> Site Permissions -> Check permissions -> enter the user name and see check whether the given permissions are reflected.

Comment: I fix it :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)